# Sanitized/Structured output of enumchildwindows API

Tags: winapi, treeview, sanitization

My task is to capture all the child windows of a main window recursively , as soon as a user clicks on the window (there can be various levels of child windows) and construct a tree structure where all child windows should be arranged in their proper hierarchy of levels.
Parent node should be the main window, immediate child windows should be the level child windows and then level 2 child windows i.e. grand children should be properly allocated to their parents.
I am using EnumChildWindows API to list all the child windows, but the problem is it lists all the children and grand-children very crudely, I am not able to how to demarcate or understand which grand children belong to which children? Is there a method by which I could produce a more structured output using EnumChildWindows?
Please give me some pointers.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EnumChildWindows()` is documented as returning all children and grand children, etc with no way of differentiating them. You can either call `GetParent()` to check what each windows parent is, or use `GetWindow()` in a loop and recursing yourself.

`GetParent()` seems safer as it makes use of the atomicness and safety of `EnumChildWindows()`.